# DtdProcessing Parse in 3.5

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, dtd

In .net 4.0 we can use property XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing with value DtdProcessing.Parse. In .net 3.5 we dont have this property, only XmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd is available.

Any other way to get this working in .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

```
[ObsoleteAttribute("Use XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing property instead.")]
public bool ProhibitDtd { get; set; }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.prohibitdtd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx